How to fuse adapters.npz into my model for fine-tuning?
This is my first fine-tuning attempt.
I have successfully created and tested my .npz file.
python3 lora.py \
 --model mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2 \
 --max-tokens 8 \
 --adapter-file /Users/sambrand/mlx-examples-main/lora/adapters.npz \
 --prompt "What is the sentiment of this movie review? Respond with a sentiment score between 1 and 10, where 1 is hate and 10 is love. The movie review is enclosed in brackets. This is the movie review: [This apology for a movie is about absolutely nothing! Rachel Griffiths must have needed the money.]"

The sentiment score is: 1
And now I want to fuse it back into Mistral 7B so that I can use it locally. But my code is producing errors.
python3 -m mlx_lm.fuse \
--model mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2 \ 
--adapter-file /Users/sambrand/mlx-examples-main/lora/adapters.npz \

Returns: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'mlx_lm.fuse' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlx_lm')
I also tried:
python3 fuse.py \
--model mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2 \ 
--adapter-file /Users/sambrand/mlx-examples-main/lora/adapters.npz \

But it returns:
usage: fuse.py [-h] [--model MODEL] [--save-path SAVE_PATH] [--adapter-file ADAPTER_FILE] [--hf-path HF_PATH] [--upload-name UPLOAD_NAME] [-d] fuse.py: error: unrecognized arguments: zsh: command not found: --adapter-file
I have been following the instructions published by Andy Peatling, and they've worked up to this point.
But I have to say I'm not entirely sure where is the model on my machine that I am hoping to fuse with adapters.npz. And I'm not sure if I'm authenticated with HF so not sure how I might download HF models through the terminal. I have been downloading models through Ollama in the terminal like ollama run mistral, and I think my saved models are these big files named sha... in .ollama/models/blobs ?
Thanks in advance for any help.

That guide might be a bit outdated. The LoRA documentation to look at is here: https://github.com/ml-explore/mlx-examples/blob/main/llms/mlx_lm/LORA.md

you should use MLX LM pip install mlx-lm.
To train do something like:

mlx_lm.lora \
    --model <path_to_model> \
    --train \
    --data <path_to_data> \
    --iters 600


To fuse, do something like

mlx_lm.fuse \
    --model mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1 \
    --hf-path mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1

